# Model unrecognized in Project ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tfs, model

I've a strange problem in my asp.net mvc5 project.

The project is build in Asp.net MVC 5 with EF 6.0 in Visual Studio 2013 (with update 2) and the solution has the following layers (these are the main):

- Entity (Layer with basic entities)
- Framework (Layer with the utils methods)
- DataBusiness (Layer with data access classes and DBContext)
- WebSite (Layer that has UI with ASP.Net MVC 5)

The project is in TFS.

When used "Get latest version" the layer WebSite recognizes our models in Models foldes, but if i close VS and restart PC, the layer WebSite don't recognize the model.

When the layer WebSite doesn't recognize the models, we don't use scafolld because the add view window doesn't show dropdownlist filled with the models (it recognizes all referenced dlls unless the models). In the views and controllers, the instances of model objects aren't recognizes too.

When i copy the solution to desktop (out of TFS), everything works normally.

This problem happens in others PCs too.

Comment: Your explanation is confusing.